# What does calling self within a class do?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I noticed in the documentation for Pytorch Lightning, it was mentioned you can call the forward method from another method in the same class just by calling `self(x)`. I haven't been able to find any info about how this works. I always thought you would call the method using `self.forward`

Evidently, it calls the forward method but how? Is there any python documentation about what's going on?

I found this at the following URL:
https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/new-project.html

The specific code fragment is this:

```
def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    ...
    z = self(x)
```

Comment: It's just calling the `__call__` method of an object

Comment: You should realize that ```f(*args, **kwargs)``` is the same as ```f.__call__(*args, **kwargs)``` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, in python, when "calling" an object, you are invoking its `__call__` method. That is,

```py
  self(x)
```

is equivalent to

```py
  self.__call__(x)
```

For pytorch `nn.Module` (and all derivative classes) `__call__` wraps around the module's `forward` function, therefore, from your perspective `self(x)` is basically forwarding `x` through the module `self`.